# How python calls each other between two classes?

Tags: python

There are 2 classes: `class A` and `class B`. In `class A`,I want to call a method in `class B`. And at the same time, in `class B`,I want to call a method in `class A`.
Like:

```
class A(object):
    """docstring for A"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.str_A = 'this is class A'
    def printA(self):
        print self.str_A
    def callB(self):
        B.printB()

class B(object):
    """docstring for B"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.str_B = 'This is class B'
    def printB(self):
        print self.str_B
    def callA(self):
        A.printA()
```

### How can I achieve this?

Well,I revise my expression.

```
class A(object):
    """docstring for A"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.str_A = 'this is class A'
    def printA(self):
        print self.str_A
    There is a function to call printB in class B names CB.
class B(object):
    """docstring for B"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.str_B = 'This is class B'
    def printB(self):
        print self.str_B
    There is a function to call printA in class A names CA.

aaa = A()
bbb = B()
aaa.CB() or bbb.CA()
```

## Of course the above sentences is wrong.How can I achieve this?How python calls each other between two classes?

Here are my two classes：
`class Stock` is a class to receive stock data，and `RtnTick` in `class Stock` can auto update.`class TradeSystem`is a class to make a GUI and when click the button,the program can make a stock exchange.GUI must display data in real time,so when `RtnTick` update the data,I want to call `self.e1_str.set()` in `class TradeSystem`for displaying. And when I click the button,I'll call `TradeCommit` in `class Stock` to make a deal.And I have omitted lots of other codes.These two classes are large.And...do you have a idea to solve this question?I'm new in python.Thanks.

```
class Stock(LtsAPI):   
    def RtnTick(self,t):
        global Sto,Configs_Path,Sto,AskPri,BidPri,AskVol,BidVol
        contract = t.InstrumentID
        if(contract in Sto):
        #Here I want to call **self.e1_str.set()** in class TradeSystem.
    def TradeCommit(self):
        #This is a function to trading.      


class TradeSystem(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()

        self.e1_str = StringVar()
        self.e1 = Entry(self.root,textvariable = self.e1_str)
        self.e1.bind('<KeyPress>')  
        self.e1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        #**self.e1_str.set()** can set the content to display.

    def Trade(self):
        self.button = Button(self.root,command = *call **TradeCommit** in class Stock*)
        #command is the function to run when triggered.
```

Comment: In the normal way of instantiating objects, e.g. `A().printA()`.

Comment: printA/B are instance methods and should be called on an object, not via the class without any object as a parameter

Comment: Class A and B is just a demonstration to explain my question.I want to know  common approach of these questions.

Comment: Even better, you should remove the classes altogether; they are not adding anything here. Use standalone functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for class metods (static methods in another languages)

```
class A(object):
    """docstring for A"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.str_A = 'this is class A'
    def printA(self):
        print self.str_A
    @classmethod
    def CB(cls):
        B().printB()

class B(object):
    """docstring for B"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.str_B = 'This is class B'
    def printB(self):
        print self.str_B
    @classmethod
    def CA(cls):
        A().printA()

aaa = A()
bbb = B()
aaa.CB() or bbb.CA()
>>> This is class B
>>> this is class A
```

But since printA() and printB() needs an instance you need to instantiate an object to invoke them

Comment: Thanks a lot.If these two classes has many methods,I just want to use only one of them,whether instancing a class in another one affects the performance of the program?And do you have a better way to avoid calling each other between two classes?

Comment: what about encapsulate your logic in a function?

Comment: Thanks.I have restatement my question.Can you give me an advice?

Comment: You should implement the observer pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Just last week I was working on something similar where I needed to instantiate class A in class B and class B in class A (Circular dependency issue). This can be used for any purpose, sharing data between both class objects, calling methods of other class object etc. Here is how I ended up doing it, you can edit it according to your needs if this is what you need.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, b=None):
    self.B = b or B(self)
    self._number  = None

  def set_number(self, number):
    self._number = number
  def get_number(self):
    return self._number

  def a(self):
    print 'Method "a" of "A"'
  def b(self):
    print 'Method "b" of "A"'
  def c(self):
    print 'Method "c" of "A"'

class B(object):
  def __init__(self, a=None):
    self.A = a or A(self)
    self._number  = None

  def set_number(self, number):
    self._number = number
  def get_number(self):
    return self._number

  def a(self):
    print 'Method "a" of "A"'
  def b(self):
    print 'Method "b" of "A"'
  def c(self):
    print 'Method "c" of "A"'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = A()
  b = B()
  a.set_number(1)
  print a.get_number()
  a.a()
  a.b()
  a.c()
  a.B.set_number(2)
  print a.B.get_number()
  a.B.a()
  a.B.b()
  a.B.c()
  b.set_number(3)
  print b.get_number()
  b.a()
  b.b()
  b.c()
  b.A.set_number(4)
  print b.A.get_number()
  b.A.a()
  b.A.b()
  b.A.c()
```

Comment: Thanks.I have restatement my question.Can you give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve this question.

```
class A(object):
    """docstring for A"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def FromAnother(self,s):
        self.Object = s

    def ExecAFunction(self,t):
        self.Object.AFunctionFromA(t)

class B(object):
    """docstring for B"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.object = A()
        self.object.FromAnother(self)
        self.object.ExecAFunction('Call a function in B  through A.')

    def AFunctionFromA(self,t):
        print t

b = B()
```

I instance the class A in class B.**init**.And I pass B itself to A's function using the instance which I just defined.Next I call B's function AFunctionFromA through function ExecAFunction in A.So now I can call functions between two classes. How do you think this method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use inheritance. Class B has to inherit all attributes and methods of Class A. For more details, please, refer to
[https://www.i2tutorials.com/python-super-with-**init**-methods/]

---

```
   [1]#base class
    class A():
       def __init__(self):
          print("In the state class")
          self.state1= "Main State"

    #derived class
    class B(A):
       def __init__(self):
          print("In the happystate class")
          self.state2= "Happy State"
          super().__init__()

    a=B()
    print(a.state1)
    print(a.state2)

<!-- end snippet -->

a=HappyState()
print(a.state1)
print(a.state2)
```